# Cannot connect to AWS EC2 via Nginx from local machine

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu that I would like to configure with Nginx. My understanding is that if Nginx is running, and I've configured my server blocks correctly, I should be able to modify my hosts file outside of my VM to serve the public IP from a custom domain.

So in my instance, Nginx is running fine:

```
~$ /etc/init.d/nginx status
 * nginx is running
```

My server block, located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` (which is symlinked to `sites-enabled`) is as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/example;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name local.example.com local.www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

`var/www/example/index.html` is an existing directory with text to display.

Per other Stackoverflow answers, I've modified my security group to include HTTP port 80:
[image]

When I ping the public IP provided in the AWS interface from my personal machine, I get a response.

But when I run `curl -v localhost` from inside the instance, I get

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

Further, when I edit my host file like this

```
my.public.ip    local.example.com
```

the connection times out.

Why cannot I not serve my `index.html` to my dummy domain when I edit my `hosts` file?

Comment: A few AWS instances stopped working for me also a few minutes ago and amazon.com, netflix.com and skype seem to be unavailable for me too. Do these sites work for you at the moment?

Comment: Yes, amazon.com and netflix.com are working for me.

Comment: Ok, AWS and above mentioned sites work for me now (but I am quite sure they were down for around 10 minutes). This is in Europe, so maybe these issues are not related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that in order to symbolically link a file, it requires that you use the full path. So when I was in `/etc/nginx`, I ran

```
ln -s sites-available/example.com sites-enabled/
```

This didn't create a "proper" symbolic link, and was failing my Nginx. I had to run

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

**Apparently, you can't do symbolic links with relative paths. They have to be absolute.**